# Making a table of signals and rhombus for layout and flow

Tags: tables, draw

I have some troubles with starting on a table for flow and layout. I would like to make it like this picture. Does anybody have a good idea? I have tried nothing and I am already out of ideas.

[image: Like this]

Kind regards Emil

Comment: This not seems to be a table. You should draw it as image. For example with `tikz` or `pstricks` packages.

Comment: I agree with Zarko. No table package is capable do make this figure is an easy way. However, since it consists of very symmetric pieces, it shoul be pretty straight forward in TikZ or a drwing application like [Ipe](http://ipe.otfried.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using this code:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}


    \usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
% Define block styles

\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw, fill=blue!20, 
    text width=3.3em, text badly centered, node distance=3cm, inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20,    text width=8em, text centered, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.90][node distance = 2cm, auto]
    % Place nodes
    \node [start] (1) {Laser cutter};
    \node [start, below of=1, node distance=1.51cm](2){Laser cutter};
    \node [start, below of=2, node distance=1.51cm](3){Laser cutter};
    \node [start, below of=3, node distance=1.51cm](4){Laser cutter};
    \node [start, below of=4, node distance=1.51cm](5){Laser cutter};
    \node [start, below of=5, node distance=1.51cm](6){Laser cutter};
    \node [start, below of=6, node distance=1.51cm](7){Laser cutter};

%% Row number 1
\node [decision, below of=1, node distance=1.5cm, yshift=0.75cm, xshift=2.42cm] (a1) {3};
\node [decision, below of=a1, node distance=1.51cm] (a2) {4};
\node [decision, below of=a2, node distance=1.51cm] (a3) {5};
\node [decision, below of=a3, node distance=1.51cm] (a4) {6};
\node [decision, below of=a4, node distance=1.51cm] (a5) {6};
\node [decision, below of=a5, node distance=1.51cm] (a6) {6};

%% Row number  2
\node [decision, below of=a1, node distance=1.5cm, yshift=0.75cm, xshift=0.75cm] (b1) {3};
\node [decision, below of=b1, node distance=1.51cm] (b2) {4};
\node [decision, below of=b2, node distance=1.51cm] (b3) {5};
\node [decision, below of=b3, node distance=1.51cm] (b4) {6};
\node [decision, below of=b4, node distance=1.51cm] (b5) {6};

%% Row number  3
\node [decision, below of=b1, node distance=1.5cm, yshift=0.75cm, xshift=.75cm] (c1) {3};
\node [decision, below of=c1, node distance=1.51cm] (c2) {4};
\node [decision, below of=c2, node distance=1.51cm] (c3) {5};
\node [decision, below of=c3, node distance=1.51cm] (c4) {6};   

%% Row number  4
\node [decision, below of=c1, node distance=1.5cm, yshift=0.75cm, xshift=.75cm] (d1) {3};
\node [decision, below of=d1, node distance=1.51cm] (d2) {4};
\node [decision, below of=d2, node distance=1.51cm] (d3) {5};

%% Row number  5
\node [decision, below of=d1, node distance=1.5cm, yshift=0.75cm, xshift=.75cm] (e1) {3};
\node [decision, below of=e1, node distance=1.51cm] (e2) {4};

%% Row number  6
\node [decision, below of=e1, node distance=1.5cm, yshift=0.75cm, xshift=.75cm] (f1) {3};




\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

[image: Picture of solution]

Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do it, with a plain `tabular` environment, some multirows and `pstricks`, inserting five empty nodes  for the outer polygon at the relevant places (either in empty cells or between rows) and constructing  from them 24 other nodes for the lines.

```
\documentclass[svgnames, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %
\usepackage{array, multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{pst-node, multido, auto-pst-pdf}
\newcounter{dept}
\newcommand*{\inbetween}[1]{\multirow{2}{*}[-0.2ex]{\thickspace#1}}

\begin{document}

    \psset{dotsize=2pt, linecolor=red, linejoin=1,linewidth =0.4pt}
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
    \[ \setcounter{dept}{0}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
    \psset{dotsize=2pt, linecolor=red, linejoin=1,linewidth =0.4pt}
    \begin{tabular}{>{\stepcounter{dept}\color{Tomato}\textbf{Dept\,%
     \Alph{dept}}}lc*{6}{>{{}\enspace\color{Tomato}\bfseries}c}}
    \noalign{\pnode[-1.5em, 0]{A}}
     &\pnode[0, 2.8ex]{B} & \inbetween{5}\\
     & & \inbetween{6} & 2 & \inbetween{6} & \\
      & & \inbetween{4} & 1 & \inbetween{3} & 2 & \inbetween{4} & \\
    & & \inbetween{4} & 4 & \inbetween{5} & 1 & \inbetween{6} & 3 \pnode[1.5em, 0.8ex]{S}\\
     & & \inbetween{2} & 5 & \inbetween{2} & 1\\
     & \pnode[-\tabcolsep, -4.8ex]{D} & \inbetween{3} & 3 \\%
     & \\
    \noalign{\pnode[-1.5em, 0ex]{C}}
     \end{tabular}
    \psset{linecolor=LightSlateGray, linewidth=1.2pt, linejoin=1,linearc =0.05}
     \pspolygon[fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=SlateGray, opacity = 0.15,linejoin=1](A)(B)(S)(D)(C)
    \multido{\n=0.142+0.143, \i=1+1}{6}{%
    \psLNode(A)(C){\n}{a\i} \psLNode(B)(D){\n}{b\i}
    \psLNode(B)(S){\n}{r\i} \psLNode(S)(D){\n}{s\i}
    \psline(a \i)(b\i)(r\i) \psline(b\i)(s\i)
    }%
    \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the contribution! :)

Answer (score 0):

[image]This solution uses a little trigonometry, but allows you to adjust the angle.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap =round]

\pgfmathsetmacro\angle{30}
\pgfmathsetmacro\textLength{2}
\pgfmathsetmacro\height{0.6}

\def\lineColor{gray}
\def\textColor{red}
\def\backColor{blue!10}

\pgfmathsetmacro\numeroLinhas{7}
\pgfmathsetmacro\cte{\height^2/tan(\angle)}
\fill[\backColor] (0,0) -- ++(\textLength,0) -- ++(\numeroLinhas*\cte,0.5*\numeroLinhas*\height) -- ++(-\numeroLinhas*\cte,0.5*\numeroLinhas*\height) -- ++(-\textLength,0) -- cycle;
\draw[thick,\lineColor] (0,\numeroLinhas*\height) -- (0,0);
\foreach \x in {0,...,\numeroLinhas}{
 \draw[thick,\lineColor] (0,\x*\height) -- +(\textLength,0);
}
\foreach \x/\y in {0/{Dept. A},1/{Dept. B},2/{Dept. C},3/{Dept. D},4/{Dept. E},5/{Dept. F},6/{Dept. G}}{
 \pgfmathsetmacro\ka{(6.5-\x)*\height}
 \pgfmathsetmacro\kb{(\numeroLinhas-\x)*\height}
 \node[\textColor] at (0.5*\textLength,\ka) {\y};
 \draw[thick,\lineColor] (\textLength,\kb) -- +(\numeroLinhas*\cte-\x*\cte,-0.5*\numeroLinhas*\height+0.5*\x*\height);
 \draw[thick,\lineColor] (\textLength,\x*\height) -- +(\numeroLinhas*\cte-\x*\cte,+0.5*\numeroLinhas*\height-0.5*\x*\height);
}
\foreach \x/\y in {0/5,1/6,2/4,3/4,4/2,5/3}{
 \pgfmathsetmacro\kc{(6-\x)*\height}
 \node[\textColor] at (\textLength+\cte ,\kc) {\y};
}
\foreach \x/\y in {0/2,1/1,2/4,3/5,4/3}{
 \pgfmathsetmacro\kd{(5.5-\x)*\height}
 \node[\textColor] at (\textLength+2*\cte, \kd) {\y};
}
\foreach \x/\y in {0/6,1/3,2/5,3/2}{
 \pgfmathsetmacro\ke{(5-\x)*\height}
 \node[\textColor] at (\textLength+3*\cte ,\ke) {\y};
}
\foreach \x/\y in {0/2,1/1,2/1}{
 \pgfmathsetmacro\kf{(4.5-\x)*\height}
 \node[\textColor] at (\textLength+4*\cte ,\kf) {\y};
}
\foreach \x/\y in {0/2,1/1}{
 \pgfmathsetmacro\kg{(4-\x)*\height}
 \node[\textColor] at (\textLength+5*\cte ,\kg) {\y};
}
\node[\textColor] at (\textLength+6*\cte ,0.5*\numeroLinhas*\height) {3};
\end{tikzpicture}[![enter image description here][1]][1]
\end{document}
```